# Fetch a data in Firebase using another data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the Firebase database structure of my project.

[image: Firebase Database of my project]

I want to fetch `complaint division`, `describe`, `stat` for the particular hostelname and roomno. How to fetch these data and display in android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all those values, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference complaintsRef = rootRef.child("Complaints");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String complaintDivision = ds.child("complaintdivision").getValue(String.class);
            //Get the other properties in the same way
            Log.d(TAG, complaintDivision);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
complaintsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Plumber Related
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic function in Firebase on Android. You can use ValueEventListeners with the database reference to do this.
The steps to achieve the desired results can be enlisted as below:

1. Create a Complaint model with the same fields as your database.
2. Get the right Firebase reference for your database node and add a ValueEventListener instance to listen for database changes.
3. Pass a DataSnapshot into the Complaint class and assign it to a Complaint object.
4. Do what you want with the Complaint object you have obtained.

Creating a Complaint class:

```
class Complaint {
        // your fields should have the same name as database fields to prevent unnecessary complications
        public String complaintdivision;
        public String complaintid;
        public String describe;
        public String hostelname;
        public String roomno;
        public String stat;

        public Complaint(){// required for Firebase

        }
    }
```

Getting the data from Firebase:

```
ArrayList<Complaint> myComplaintArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Complaints").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot complaint: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Complaint c = complaint.getValue(Complaint.class);
            myComplaintArrayList.add(c);// you should have an ArrayList<Complaint> for this loop
        }
        // do what you want with the items you obtained
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

This is pretty much all of it. If you are still having problems, you should read a tutorial on Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

So to fetch the data you would first declare a Firebase DatabaseReference object that points to your database:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

You would then write a query using this object:

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("Complaints");
```

Now you attach a SingleValueEventListener to this query:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Write a for-each loop to cycle through your node's children
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Create an instance of your model class to
                //store the received data

                //Make sure you have an empty constructor in your model class
                Complaint complaint = data.getValue(Complaint.class);

                //then simply call your getters on the complaint object
                //to get what you need
                complaint.getComplaintDivision();
                complaint.getDescription();
                //...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

To fetch more specifically, you just modify the query. 
For more information on queries, [see this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)